# Detect Mixed Content message from third party on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, https, compatibility, mixed-content

Is it possible to detect the mixed content error provided by Chrome with JavaScript?

*Background to why I need access to it:*

I'm currently using streaming from a third party that uses http and I'm using https (this is not possible to change from either party), however, I would like to detect if the browser is receiving a mixed content message (which Chrome console is) and then do/show something different in this situation.

Older Android/Desktop Chrome browsers are compatible with this and I'd like to keep this functionality while also managing this for newer webkit oriented browsers.

Comment: Every modern browser will _not_ allow this. Catering to older browsers only doesn’t make much sense (unless you have a very special user base here maybe?) – so you need to find a real solution, rather than a way to only catch the console messages it creates.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I understand what you're saying completely, I'm catering for video streaming on mobile devices with a website that requires https, however i'm unable to convince the third party to change to this. The mixed content with the video seems to work fine for Chrome <40 on Android but the streaming has completely stopped recently. Therefore, I was considering throwing the video to an external tab if the error message was received (and if I'm able to detect it).

Comment: Maybe this method will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38026278/1682761